# Shown in elementary school; sci-fi mini-series with kids about a book or reading. Tonal notes involved

Tags: tv, story-identification, music

For years I've been trying to remember more about this little mini series thing they showed us in school.  A class or two of us at a time would be herded into the library adn we'd all watch on a wheel-out t.v.  I can't remember how many "episodes" of it we watched, but it definitely seemed to be a serial type of thing.  Here's what I can recall:

- Live action.
- Involved kids and adults.
- Possibly in the future? Dystopian?  I seem to remember them in the forest.
- There seemed to be a lack of knowledge in this world; not being able to read?  The art of the written word?  Present day children taken to the future for the knowledge they have on reading this book?
- There was something very important about a particular book.  I believe we got a little information each time, building up to having an understanding about the big goal.
- There was something to do with music / tones, which I believe were from a synthesizer.  Perhaps put in the right order to create a song?  Sort of Close Encounters of the Third Kind-ish.  Occasionally I can almost hear the sound of these notes.  The closest I have ever heard like it would be from near the end of "Bound Too Long" by the Crystal Method.
- There may have been some sort of emblem on the book, akin to the orin in The Never Ending Story.
- This would have been around 1984, but I don't know how old the series might have been.

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 6):

If i'm not mistaken it is "Tomes and Talismans."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomes_%26_Talismans

Comment: This was my first thought as well. The year would have been a bit off, but this certainly feels correct on the other counts, to my memory.

Comment: I watched this in "Library Sciences" in, oh I guess it was '87. I remember the "tonal key" they had to put together, and that was what made me think of this. I looked at some of the youtube videos and the whole thing is pretty strange, but it was pbs in the 80's.

Comment: I think that's it!  Thanks so much.  You wouldn't believe how long that's been stuck in my head, lol.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it was called Storylords.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB66BAA211D91F0D5